# How to store data which is essentially a list tied to a unique value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, list, store, synonym

this question has probably been asked a thousand times but I didnt know how to formulate it in google so I didn't get any good answers.

Let's say I have a table "words" in SQL which stores some word in the first column of each row. What I want to do here is to store all the synonyms to that word as well and link them to that word in the first column. For instance if I have the word "angry", I want to tie the words "mad, bitter, enraged, furious, irritated" etc. to that word, so if I want to get all the synonyms with an SQL query I can easily do so.

As I understand it, trying to store lists in a cell is a no go. The only thing I can think of is to have a row entry for "angry" for each and everyone of its synonyms. But if a word has a lot of synonyms, or I have a lot of words, it feels like there will be a lot of entries (and a lot of unnecessary duplicates of each word). Is there a better practice to achieve my goal than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use two tables, one for each entity with defined foreign key relationships.  The tables would look like:

```
create table words (
    WordId int not null primary key auto_increment,
    Word varchar(255)
    . . .
);

create table synonyms (
    SynonymId int not null primary key auto_increment,
    WordId int not null,
    Synonym varchar(255),
    . . .
    constraint fk_wordid foreign key (WordId) references Words(WordId)
);
```

If synonyms are necessarily words, then you would use the id in the second table:

```
create table synonyms (
    SynonymId int not null primary key auto_increment,
    WordId int not null,
    SynonymWordId int not null,
    . . .
    constraint fk_wordid foreign key (WordId) references Words(WordId),
    constraint fk_synonymwordid foreign key (SynonymWordId) references Words(WordId)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also use two tables but my 2nd one would be different than Gordon's.

```
 table word
 wordID  int pk
 word varchar
 other fields

table synonym
wordID int FK to word
synonymID int FK to word
pk is both fields
```

query for synonyms of angry

```
select s.word
from word w join synonym sy on w.wordID = sy.wordID
join word s on sy.synonymID = s.wordID
where w.word = 'angry'
```

Comment: We will probably always disagree over the use of synthetic versus composite primary keys.  Both methods have their merits.  Cheers.

Comment: When two people have a difference of opinion, the only thing you can be sure of is that each was capable of forming one.

Answer (score 0):

A table with words:

```
CREATE TABLE words (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  word varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO words VALUES (1,'angry'), (2,'mad'), (3,'bitter'),
(4,'enraged'), (5,'furious'), (6,'irritated'),
(7,'nice'), (8,'pleasant'), (9,'cute');
```

a table with synonym groups

```
CREATE TABLE synonymgroups (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  description varchar(100)
); 
INSERT INTO synonymgroups VALUES (1,'synonyms for "angry"'),
(2,'synonyms for "nice"');
```

and a table with group - word mapping

```
CREATE TABLE synonyms (
  synonymgroupid integer NOT NULL REFERENCES synonymgroups,
  wordid integer NOT NULL REFERENCES words,
  PRIMARY KEY (synonymgroupid,wordid)
); 
INSERT INTO synonyms(synonymgroupid,wordid) VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3),
(1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,7), (2,8), (2,9);
```

Find all synonyms for word "mad":

```
SELECT s.wordid, w.word, s.synonymgroupid, sg.description
FROM synonyms s
  JOIN words w ON w.id=s.wordid
  JOIN synonymgroups sg ON sg.id=s.synonymgroupid
WHERE s.synonymgroupid IN (
  SELECT synonymgroupid
  FROM synonyms
  JOIN words ON words.id=synonyms.wordid
  WHERE words.word='mad'
);
```

PS. SQL databases are probably not the best tool for that kind of task. This is just an example.